# possible alternative for playing video(using videoView) inside listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-videoview

i'm trying to make something similar to what Google+ does for video in list-view(i guess its video). 
in Google+ while scrolling list if there's video in visible area it automatically starts playing even when i'm scrolling until it gets out of the screen.

now i know that video wont play properly when list-view is scrolling. so i guess Google+ has made some sort of workaround to play video.

first i though of using Animation Drawable(by somehow getting images from video at some interval). but if i want to play a video of 6 sec at 10-12 fps(min) that's around 60-72 images. and Animation Drawable loads all images at once,so in this case it will immediately gives out of memory error.

so any other suggestion?

**Update :**
currently i have managed it to work somehow by using a scroll listener on listview. 
here's how i have done so far.
i am detecting which view is in center and if the listview is not scrolling at all (detected using scroll listener) the videoView in that particular view starts playing. if user touches the screen to move list view video playback is stopped, a frame of that particular instance is grabbed and displayed on top of the video view, i'm hiding videoView after the frame is grabbed. also using "notifyDataSetChanged" of BaseAdapter and a couple of flags to makes sure the listview(listview recycles View so) works fine.

well this works but not an elegant solution. it flickers when user touches the screen and stuck for a moment when "getCurrentVideoFrame" is called in main thread.

**update 2:**

ok so i think there may be a different way using ffmpeg. 
here's what i am gonna do:
get images from a video file using ffmpeg at predefined fps.
replacing these images in imageview at defined rate using asynctask "publish update" mechanism.

any thoughts?

Comment: Did you find any solution on that?

Comment: @Piotr i have managed to play image on imageview at predefined fps using ffmpeg. dont have any working demo on hand but i can tell you the procedure if you want.

Comment: do you have any working demo to see it?

Comment: @keybee Please check  https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java

It plays mp4 in TextureView. TextureView can be used with listview or scrollview without glitch that we have when we use SurfaceView . It uses MediaCodec to display decoded stream on surface.